# How to add another .i swig file to an Extension?

Tags: swig, setuptools, deb, python-extensions, python-wheel

I have created a Python interface to my library using SWIG. This Python interface uses numpy. All of this works correctly.

Now, I want to package this Python interface into a Python wheel. Packaging for Windows works correctly.

```
myext = Extension( "MyExt",
    sources = ["MyExt.i"],
    swig_opts=["-py3", "-I/usr/include", "-includeall"],
    libraries=["mylib"],
)
```

On Windows, compilation occurs directly where all the sources and `setup.py` files are. This is not the case for Linux when building my `bdist_deb` (same for `bdist_rpm`), and here is my problem.

The file `MyExt.i` includes `numpy.i`. Therefore, I should add it as a `source` file of the extension. However if I do this, then `setuptools` also tries to run swig on `numpy.i`. This is not what I want. I haven't found any of the other parameters of `Extension` that would accept such a file.

Someone knows how to get out of this issue?

Comment: This is really just a wild guess, but perhaps you need to list numpy.i in a file named MANIFEST.in (this is for telling setuptools which files belong to a source distribution if they cannot be automatically determined as dependencies)?

Comment: @m7thon This is the correct answer.